# One MathJax comment to ruin them all. Keep defined macros local

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, mathjax

There have already been some proposals to [limit MathJax in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135323/260760) in general, or to [inline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279404/260760) only. And while this is somewhat connected, it can be extended to answers and questions, too.

I found a way that has the potential to completely ruin most of the MathJax for the following posts. I am certain that such instances will be rare (if ever) and that they could be dealt with individually. However, I see the problem, that someone destroys something completely unintentional. And there is already an easy fix for that.

MathJax provides the functionality to define and **redefine** commands. The latter is the source of the problem, as you can also redefine defaults. The following screenshot may exaggerate this.

[image: MathJax comment breaks answer]

In the above I redefine the `\frac` command, basically inverting all fractions. (The command itself is invisible.) I know that you need to obtain the privilege to post comments, but we had more determined trolls than that. I am not concerned that this is a big problem, but there is an easy fix for this.

The Mathjax configuration should load [`begingroup`](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#begingroup) and issue a `$\begingroup$` at the beginning and a `$\endgroup$` at the end of each post, keeping defined macros local. To guard against malicious comments it might be worthwhile considering doing the same for comments, although I cannot judge how that would affect load times.

Comment: This has long been a concern on [math.se]: [The scope of \newcommand is the entire page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4130), and [Using the Begingroup Extension of MathJax?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/7048).

Comment: Isn't it easy for a troll to get around auto-injection of `\xgroup` by just including `\endgroup` at the start of their post? Mm... I guess each other piece of content would be encapsulated in its own `\xgroup` commands... but if someone redefined, e.g., `\frac`, effectively globally as you do in your example, wouldn't that propagate as the default into the 'subscopes'?

Comment: A quick test question confirms that, yes, redefining defaults at the page-level scope *does* propagate into the `group`-ed blocks. `group`ing will protect against `newcommand` leakage into other Jax, but cannot protect against malicious top-level redefinition of defaults.

Comment: This was changed in [January 2019](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4130/the-scope-of-newcommand-is-the-entire-page/29621#29621). (Although it broke some of the existing posts/existing comments, but that's for a separate discussion.) The change is also mentioned in this list: [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/322016#322016).

Comment: @Martin Thank you for the information, I wouldn't have looked otherwise.